# How to assign onopen handler before opening a websocket in javascript

Tags: javascript, websocket

As I understand it, the standard way to open a websocket in javascript is like this

```
 let socket = new WebSocket(host);
 socket.onopen = function(){
   console.log('socket opened');
 }
```

The concern I have with this code is that it depends on the timing of things.

Suppose the server responds very quickly but for some reason the javascript on the client executes very slowly. Would it not be theoretically possible for the socket to be created but the onopen handler to be assigned sometime later?

I'd prefer

```
 create socket
 assign onopen handler
 open socket
```

but it seems this isn't possible since the statement to create a new socket also opens it. Attempting to assign an onopen handler to a null socket variable is an error.

Is there any way to create a WebSocket without opening it?

The establishment of the websocket connection may happen asynchronously, but I don't see how that eliminates the possibility that it completes before the onopen handler assignment.

Comment: The socket connection is asynchronous. I don't think what you are worried about is possible

Comment: Thanks charlietfl, I've added to my question slightly.

Comment: Take a look at this very simple example https://jsfiddle.net/8vcgmr5p/. Synchronous code will run before asynchronous operations due to the way the Event Loop works. In this case I used a very basic setTimeout with no delay to demonstrate